# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: json, laravel, collections, eloquent, response

Method:

```
public function users(){
    $users = User::with(['profile'])->customer()->get();
    return Response::json($users);
}
```

Response:

The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

```
* @return $this
*
* @throws \UnexpectedValueException
*/

public function setContent($content)
    {
        if (null !== $content && !is_string($content) && !is_numeric($content) && !is_callable(array($content, '__toString'))) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "%s" given.', gettype($content)));
    }
```

What im doing wrong? I've read some similar questions but i cant find the error or any solution.

Best regards!

Comment: Im using laravel 4.2

Comment: what happens when you dd($users) before returning anything?

Comment: What do you want to receive?

Comment: Just the response of the dd().  What we are looking for is to make sure you are receiving an instance of a Collection.

Comment: I need a collection json, when make printr obtain an Object, but when i use Response::json turns to false.

Comment: dd helper is not available on 4.2

Comment: Have you tried json encoding $users before sending it into the response?  This would result in the parameter your sending in being a string, which the error says is okay.  Otherwise, you need to confirm that the object you are sending in does implement __toString().  In newer versions of Laravel at least, the Collection class does.

Comment: I never tried that :?

Answer (score 1):

Incredible, you will not believe that... A user has an accent that utf8_decode could not process, i've updated and works fine.

Solved replacing ì to í.